# How can I use function in C++ to create a sequence?

Tags: c++

My goal is to create an immutable function (functional programming) using "accumulate" in C++. I created a dummy list that generates 1's based on the position I send, which will be 6. So the list at the start contains {1,1,1,1,1,1}. I tried using accumulate to somehow use the information on this list and make the fibonacci sequence into a new list. The result has to be {1,1,2,3,5,8}

Here is what I have.

```
list<int> immutableFibonacci(int position)
{
const size_t fixedListSize(position);
list<int> newList(position, int(1));
list<int> copyList;
list<int>::iterator it = newList.begin();

if (position <=2)
{
    return newList; //returns {1,1} or {1}
}

while (position>0)
{
    advance(it, 1);
    sum = accumulate(newList.begin(),it, 0); 
    copyList.push_back(sum);
    position--;
}
    return copyList;
}
```

What I have so far will return copyList as {1,2,3,4,5,6}. Can someone please push me in the right direction on what to do? I tried researching quite a bit.

Comment: FYI usually you want `vector` rather than `list` if you just want a container.

Comment: *Data* can be immutable, functions can’t. Furthermore, `std::accumulate` seems like a badly fitting algorithm here.

Comment: In my function I am being required to use accumulate

Comment: `std::accumulate` seems overkill to do `Fib[n] = Fib[n - 2] + Fib[n - 1]`.

Comment: `std::generate` seems like a much better algorithm to *generate* the sequence.

Comment: I have already used that in my recursive function. This needs to be more of an iterative way of returning the fib list without data mutability.

Comment: Can you please define 'immutable function'?

Comment: the data (list) cannot be modified. I have to use accumulate to create a new list instead. and return a fibonacci list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    std::vector<int> s = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(),std::vector<int>{},
                                        [](const std::vector<int>& a, int b) 
                    {
                        std::vector<int> d = a;
                        if(a.size()<2)
                        {
                            d.push_back(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            auto start = d.rbegin();
                            auto first = *start;
                            start++;
                            auto second = *start;
                            d.push_back(first+second);
                        }
                        return d;
                    });

    std::cout << "Fibo: " <<'\n';

    for( auto c : s )
    {
        std::cout << c << "-";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

But I also think it is a bit too much overhead, for something that simple.

EDIT: Remember to compile that with: g++ --std=c++14 fibo.cpp -o fibo.

EDIT: If you don't want to use the lambda function look here: [How can I modify this Fibonacci code in C++ to use a function instead of lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400018/how-can-i-modify-this-fibonacci-code-in-c-to-use-a-function-instead-of-lambda/39403913#39403913)

Comment: It worked liked magic! will you be kind enough to explain what is going on so I can understand this better? Is this honoring immutability?

Comment: [Congratulations.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400018/how-can-i-modify-this-fibonacci-code-in-c-to-use-a-function-instead-of-lambda) You just added another [Cargo Cult Programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) to the world.

Comment: @coding_xeno: Because ```v``` can be const you get a new vector ```s``` with your result. I'm guess you mean variables that with immutability; ```v``` does not get altered in the process. About std::accumulate: First and second parameter are clear. The third one is an empty vector. You have to provide it for the template deduction. The fourth one is a lambda function that by giving the vector ```a``` and a value ```b``` that is every deref'd ```v``` iterator. ```a``` is the ```d``` vector of the last call and get "accumulated" in the process.

Comment: @user4581301: Really? Then tell me what I should have done? Not help him or what?

Answer (score 1):

this method creates a 'container-like' object which exposes iterators via `begin()` and `end()`

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct fib_iterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, long long>
{
    fib_iterator(std::size_t torun = 0) : to_run(torun) {}
    value_type operator*() const {
        return value();
    }
    fib_iterator& operator++()
    {
        --to_run;
        switch(preamble)
        {
            case 2:
                --preamble;
                return *this;
            case 1:
                --preamble;
                return *this;
        }

        auto next = value();
        x = y;
        y = next;
        return *this;
    }

    value_type value() const
    {
        switch(preamble)
        {
            case 2:
                return 0;
            case 1:
                return 1;
        }
        return x + y;
    }

    bool operator==(const fib_iterator& r) const {
        return to_run == r.to_run;
    }

    bool operator!=(const fib_iterator& r) const {
        return to_run != r.to_run;
    }

    long long x = 0;
    long long y = 1;
    std::size_t preamble = 2;
    std::size_t to_run;
};

struct fibonacci_sequence
{
    fibonacci_sequence(std::size_t length) : length_(length) {}

    fib_iterator begin() const { return { length_ }; }
    fib_iterator end() const { return { }; }

    std::size_t length_;
};

int main()
{
    for (auto i : fibonacci_sequence(50))
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

sample output:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 
1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393,
196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887,
9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141,
267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073,
4807526976, 7778742049,
```