# How can I modify this code to use a function instead of lambda?

Tags: c++

I have a working fibonacci function that is returning a list of fibonacci numbers from a dummy list {1,1,1,1,1,1}. Here is my code.

```
list<int> immutableFibonacci(int position)
{
list<int> oldList(position, int(1));

list<int> newList = accumulate(oldList.begin(), oldList.end(), list<int>{},
    [](const list<int> a, int b)
{
    list<int> d = a;

    if (a.size()<2)
    {
        d.push_back(1);
    }
    else
    {
        auto start = d.rbegin();
        auto first = *start;
        start++;
        auto second = *start;
        d.push_back(first + second);
    }
    return d;
});
    return newList;
}
```

Instead of passing the lambda expression [](const list a, int b) to calculate, I want to pass the name of a function. How can I go about doing this? It would basically be a function inside the function immutableFibonacci, but I am having trouble in doing this.

Comment: Did you try writing a function and passing it to accumulate?

Comment: I'm not sure how to start it since I barely know what is going on in [](const list<int> a, int b)

Comment: @coding_xeno: Take a look at my answer. Sorry for the lambda definition in the previous answered question. I sometimes get a bit lazy. It's the fault of the lambdas. I like them too much! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
list<int> newList = accumulate(oldList.begin(), oldList.end(), list<int>{},
    [](const list<int> a, int b)
{
    list<int> d = a;

    if (a.size()<2)
    {
        d.push_back(1);
    }
    else
    {
        auto start = d.rbegin();
        auto first = *start;
        start++;
        auto second = *start;
        d.push_back(first + second);
    }
    return d;
});
```

the above, and pass an actual function, like this. You need function pointers:

```
list<int> newList = accumulate(oldList.begin(), oldList.end(), list<int>{},
    funcname);

//Below is the function    

list<int> funcname(list<int> a, int b) {
    list<int> d = a;

    if (a.size()<2)
    {
        d.push_back(1);
    }
    else
    {
        auto start = d.rbegin();
        auto first = *start;
        start++;
        auto second = *start;
        d.push_back(first + second);
    }
    return d;
}
```

For a custom comparator, you could either pass a function pointer, or a lambda, and for your example, you used a lambda.

Comment: this does not seem to be working. There is a semicolon already closing accumulate. So why is there a semicolan after the return d;

Comment: return d;
}); <--

Comment: @coding_xeno Pretty sure that's a cut-n-paste mistake. I recommend putting the function above the call to `accumulate`. Saves you a forward declaration. Are you absolutely certain this is the approach you want to take to solve your problem? I wholeheartedly recommend using code that you understand over stuff you got from the Internet. Much better odds of passing the exams.

Comment: well it worked fine if I had the function defined globally... it didnt work when I placed it within the function itself

Comment: `std::accumulate` will also accept an instance of a functor. That is, a struct/class that has a `list<int> operator()( list<int> const &a, int b ) const { ... }` member function. The lambda, in effect, creates this for you.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for pointing that out, I was in a hurry, and it is fixed now

Comment: @coding_xeno, you must define it globally, you have no choice, functions must either be declared globally or within a class, not within a parameter unless the function in question is a lambda

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I defined it globally by doing list<int> funcname(list<int> a, int b); and after that... I only get one error. that a semicolon is needed at list<int> funcname(list<int> a, int b) { <---

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using my answer :-) -> [How can I use accumulate in C++ to create the Fibonacci sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397254/how-can-i-use-accumulate-in-c-to-create-the-fibonacci-sequence/39397725#39397725)

Here is my solution for your question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <functional>



auto fibo (std::vector<int>& a, int b) 
{
     if(a.size()<2)
     {
          a.push_back(1);
     }
     else
     {
          auto start = a.rbegin();
          auto first = *start;
          start++;
          auto second = *start;
          a.push_back(first+second);
     }
     return a;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    std::vector<int> s = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                                     std::vector<int>{}, fibo);

    std::cout << "Fibo: " <<'\n';

    for( auto c : s )
    {
        std::cout << c << "-";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Remember to compile that with: `g++ --std=c++14 fibo.cpp -o fibo`.

Comment: @coding_xeno : you are welcome and if you like this why not upvote my answer. I would be very grateful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a functor inside the immutableFibonacci function like this:

```
struct
{
    list<int> operator()(const list<int>& a, int b) const
    {
        //...then put your lambda code here...
    }
} funObj;
```

And then just use the "funObj" name inside the accumulate function instead of lambda. That's all.